# UITableView custom section header disappear

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a view that I'm trying to use as a header section of my UITableView.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UILabel *name= (UILabel *)[myView viewWithTag:200];
    name.text = @"title";

    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row-bg-red.png"]];

    return myView;
}
```

It loads ok, but when I scroll down and the next header appears, the previous does the opposite: it disappears.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Typically, myView is a scoped var within that method.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you reuse the one view. This is not possible. Each view (UIView subclass) can be in the view hierarchy exactly once. So what probably happens in your case is that when you set the second section view, it gets removed from its original place where you put it last time for the first section.

You can create every time a new section header view directly in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method.